# Repeated incorrect time in Multipass clients with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: time, clock, multipass

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and installed Multipass to quickly bootstrap small Ubuntu VMs for testing. However, these VMs consistently show a strong time drift, and do not sync with the host OS (which has the correct system time).

On the host:

```sh
$ date
Mo 25. Sep 20:40:24 CEST 2023
```

Inside Multipass:

```sh
$ date
Sun Sep 24 22:23:43 CEST 2023
$ timedatectl status
               Local time: Sun 2023-09-24 22:24:27 CEST
           Universal time: Sun 2023-09-24 20:24:27 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2023-09-25 17:04:01
                Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

The Multipass "local time" is off by a day minus 2h, the "Universal time" is off by a day, the "RTC time" is off by about 5 hours (approx), ... what is going on here?

I could run another `ntpd` inside Multipass but I'd rather avoid that and just have Multipass reuse my host clock without inventing its own time.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it this bug? Or different? https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/982

Comment: That looks very similar. I implemented the workaround mentioned there and will see if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user535733 is right. There is actually an issue with Multipass in that it "stops time" when the computer is suspended, and/or when the daemon is suspended. This is not an issue with VM server farms which run 24/7, but it is with desktop devel machines.

Workaround: In each multipass VM, do

```
$ echo PollIntervalMinSec=32 >> /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
$ echo PollIntervalMaxSec=2048 >> /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
```

This works for me:

```sh
ubuntu@myvm:~$ timedatectl 
               Local time: Mon 2023-10-02 19:27:57 CEST
           Universal time: Mon 2023-10-02 17:27:57 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2023-10-02 17:27:56
                Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no
ubuntu@myvm:~$ logout
~$ timedatectl 
               Local time: Mo 2023-10-02 19:28:02 CEST
           Universal time: Mo 2023-10-02 17:28:02 UTC
                 RTC time: Mo 2023-10-02 17:28:03
                Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```